# MutationObserver characterData usage without childList

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, mutation-observers

Up until recently I thought that `childList : true` on `MutationObserver` was to be used when child node is being added/removed
e.g from `<span id='mama-span'> </span>` to `<span id='mama-span'><span id='baby-span'></span></span>`

and `characterData : true` was to be used when text inside observed element chages e.t `<span> </span>` to `<span> with some text </span>`. [It turns out that for text change to be observed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521073/mutationobserver-on-span-text-change-does-not-trigger) one needs to add `childList : true`.

**Can anyone think of situation in which [characterData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit) would be used without childList? What is it used for?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can observe a **text node** directly. In that case you don't need to observe **childList**. There are many cases where it could be useful, in a **contenteditable** element for example. Like this:

```js
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id').childNodes[0];

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});
 
// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: false, characterData: true };
 
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

```html
<div id='some-id' contenteditable='true'>Modify content</div>
```

Comment: <del>Hi, in my test i found that if i delete all the text then no event will be logged any more. Why and how can i solve this?</del>

Comment: well we need to consider `subtree`, `attributeOldValue` and `characterDataOldValue`. Solved.