# Read TextContent of Text changed via other JS script

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to calculate and show an automatic price when quantity & variations of a product are changed. It is all working pretty well, I am though having trouble reading the price that changes ( depending on variation) . I need to use that value to calculate some other stuff. 
The price updates automatically through a third party script, so my idea was to read out the value and then reuse it for my purposes. Unfortunately, the value I read is never the update one, but the previous price. I hope I was clear enough. Here an example: 
[image]

Everytime I change the color I have a different price displaying ( via ajax) how can I directly access the changed price value and use it?

Here some of the code:

```
var amount = document.querySelector('.single_variation_wrap .woocommerce- 
variation-price .woocommerce-Price-amount')
var price = amount.textContent.split("€")
var changeComma = price[0].replace(/,/g, ".");
var convertedPrice = parseFloat(changeComma)
var totalPrice = convertedPrice;

var el = document.querySelector('[name="quantity"]');
var flavor = document.getElementById('flavors');
var basePackSize  = 6;


function changeVariation (){
 if(multiple && multiple.checked === true){
 price = totalPrice * 0.9
 CalculateQuantity(basePackSize,price)
 }else{
  CalculateQuantity(basePackSize,totalPrice)
 }}


function CalculateQuantity(basePackSize, price) {
 var total = price * el.value
};

el.addEventListener("change", function(){
  changeVariation()
})
flavor.addEventListener('change', function(e) { 
 changeVariation()

})
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: You likely need a timeout or add the reading of the price in the success of the Ajax or on add to cart

Comment: You can look into a [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). You can observe and run a function when an elements text changes. [This might be a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521966/mutationobserver-characterdata-usage-without-childlist)

Comment: Thanks! I did research but I dont seem to find a nice solution for this issue. I will post my code example

Comment: In your ajax code when you retrieve the new data you need to call some callback function to do your calculations, changeVariation() in your case for example. If you bind it to a change event like you did now, it will run before the ajax call is finished. Assuming your ajax call is asynchronous which they are by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have similar works in the past. I guess you using Wordpress with Woocommerce plugin and another 3rd party plugin. The easier solution is by using significant delay by using `setTimeout()`. Just like suggested by some people in the comment. It is because your 3rd party plugin has some tasks in the process while your script gets the value before the 3rd party tasks are done. Even it felt like a lucky guess. And in some case, the 3rd party tasks process may longer than your timeout when your web is live.

However, in my previous project, I was using another approach. Another thing I can suggest to you is by finding their script which doing the process, copy it to your theme and modify it to match with what you need. In the same time, you should take it out from Wordpress hooks, then "re-hooks" with your modified script. I was using plugin named "Variation Master" for Woocommerce. So, my "re-hooks" script looks like this:

```
remove_action("wp_ajax_ced_vm_get_variation_gallery_for_single", 'ced_vm_get_variation_gallery_for_single');
remove_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_ced_vm_get_variation_gallery_for_single", 'ced_vm_get_variation_gallery_for_single');

add_action("wp_ajax_ced_vm_get_variation_gallery_for_single", 'dx_vm_get_variation_gallery_for_single');
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_ced_vm_get_variation_gallery_for_single", 'dx_vm_get_variation_gallery_for_single');
```

My Javascript modifications were more to gallery task instead price calculation like yours. So, the hooks you need to manage should be different.